# I need an editorial calendar to manage my social updates..any advice?

Tags: database, calendar, marketing

I'm a freelance artist that struggles on social media. I have a lot of them but I'm not able to organize everything well. They are also a lot different from one another, so I'm not able to use services such as Buffer or Hootsuite in order to streamline a post from Patreon or from DeviantArt or from a Society6 upload. I just need a way to calendarize, categorize and keep track of all of my uploadable material (photos, videos, text posts, blogs, or links).
I've been searching such a thing from a while now, and I'm unable to find something suitable. I don't need something that is specifically designed for social networks, but something that is:

- a calendar, with all the common and needed functionalities of a calendar (events, reminders, locations - locations will be used as laptop, mobile phone, pc, etc)
- a place in which I can set all of my social connections (as tags, or as categories, not necessarly as links or real connections - I don't need an auto-poster)
- a place in which I can put all of my uploadable material (blog posts, tweets, photos, videos - so various file formats)
- a system capable to automatically categorize my posts based on their type, i.e: short txts on everything but Pinterest and Wordpress, or photos on everything including Pinterest, or videos only on YouTube
- a system capable of scheduling such categorized material, and letting me mark items as done for a certain category but not for another, in order to keep track of what I already posted and what's missing instead.
- a system that let me set 'preferred hours' for certain categories (intended as channels or social networks), in order to build the perfect schedule
- this system can be offline, online, or even on mobile phone, best if it is cross platform but really, I don't really need direct social collections, bulk uploads, or auto posting functionalitis

I'm now going to give a short description of what I want to do, since english is not my primary language and I can often miss something important.

Basically, I want a place in which I can put everything. A sketch, a pic, or in which I can write a text or simply drag in a word doc. Everything that I produce as an artist, in order to spread my activity online and gain visibility. I produce a lot of material since I'm always working on a commission or on a big project. Sketches, short thoughts, finished artworks and so on. Maybe I can sit at my desktop on monday, collecting everything from my past week and putting it into the system. This system automatically detects the type of post (or of file, since I'm not talking social specifically) and assigns to each entry a tag based on the social networks (or tags, categories, something to mark it) in which the type of file can fit (i.e. short thoughts on Twitter, less than 140 chars, longer posts on everything else except from Twitter and Pinterest that doesn't accept that kind of post). Next, based on the given 'mark', the system is able to tell me (of course, based on my preference) that certain files can be posted at a certain hour on a certain social. So, the system is giving to every file that I put in a tag (based on the type of file, so short post, long post, photo, etc), a category (based on the social networks), date and time for each category (keeping in mind also a possible queue of files so if this Monday it's occupied it sets the post to the next available one) and a checklist that lets me track which categories I have already managed and which not.

Thank you in advance, I really don't know how can I do something like this, but I hope that there is a solution. Maybe in some database system, or spreadsheets connections, I don't really know. Thank you :)